# Devise token Auth response does not include manually generated header tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth

I had to implement my own confirmations_controller because I use cellphone instead of email.

```rb
# controllers/verifications_controller.rb
class VerificationsController < ApplicationController

  def verification
    # ... ops related to verification ...
    if @resource.errors.empty?
      @resource.create_token
      @resource.save!
      puts @resource.valid? # true
      puts @resource.active_for_authentication? # true
      puts @resource.tokens # {"IJrCUArkVVqMc7N9hPl0OQ"=>{"token"=>"$2a$04$6TQf.Kq96n1WC2M4CjyDM.qV358sMOyuHOeSZFtkH4YGJ5EXtxYvK", "expiry"=>1597117964}}
      render_verification_success
    end

    private
    def render_verification_success
      render json: @resource, status: 200
    end
  end
end
```

`puts response.headers` in rspec:

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Download-Options"=>"noopen", "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"=>"none", "Referrer-Policy"=>"strict-origin-when-cross-origin", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"W/\"972afd62475c3a5f81ac1bf7802f83d7\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"01186624-232e-4dea-aece-693b02f27082", "X-Runtime"=>"0.105639", "Content-Length"=>"512"}
```

I guided my implementation from this https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/bef1b0b7172459dff0d0a23f8d911a7b23b9a6c7/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/confirmations_controller.rb#L15

Answer (score 1):

Devise Token Auth takes user header tokens from the **@token** variable.

Change

```rb
@resource.create_token
```

to

```rb
@token = @resource.create_token
```

I also added

```rb
sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)
```

To sign in the user.

I found the solution in: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/bef1b0b7172459dff0d0a23f8d911a7b23b9a6c7/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb#L29